# Laravel echo event broadcasting with pusher and vueJS is not working like written in the docs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher, laravel-echo

Hi guys i'm really confused because I have read the docs on how to pass values in a broadcast by doing this.

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
 return new PresenceChannel('room.'.$this->message->room_id);
}
```

and it's giving me a auth error which is not authorized. it seems the parameter is not being read in broadcastOn instead it is being read in the Echo.join because when i do this everything works fine.

```
Echo.join('room.' + 1)
.listen('NewMessage', (e) => {
    //
});
```

But i don't want to pass a 1 to all my join i need it to be dynamic.
Is there a way to pass the $this->message->room_id to the Echo.join?
If it helps here is my channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('room.{roomId}', function ($user, $roomId) {
   return //logic is here
});
```

I've tried what is written in the docs which is

```
Echo.join('room.${roomId}')
    .here(...)
    .joining(...)
    .leaving(...)
    .listen('NewMessage', (e) => {
        //
    });
```

but it's giving me a Invalid channel name exception.
I've searched the whole internet but no answer. Maybe i'm missing something obvious here. Send help please.

Comment: You're trying to use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), but you need to use backticks `\`room.${roomId}\``

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) they should be between `backticks`, not single quotes, so you should be subscribing to:

```
Echo.join(`room.${roomId}`)
    .here(...)
    .joining(...)
    .leaving(...)
    .listen('NewMessage', (e) => {
        //
});
```

Comment: Hi thank you for responding

Broadcast::channel("room.{$roomId}", function ($user, $roomId) {
   return //logic is here
});

this is giving me a undefined variable roomId.

Comment: and also this
Echo.join(`room.${roomId}`)
    .here(...)
    .joining(...)
    .leaving(...)
    .listen('NewMessage', (e) => {
        //
    });
is giving me a Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: companyId is not defined"

Comment: It's giving me some undefined variables exceptions

Comment: Sorry the `php` thing was my fault, I forgot you were defining a channel, I'll update my answer. The `undefined` issues are not from this piece of code, but if you have defined them in `data` then make sure they have `this` before them `this.companyId` etc

Comment: I don't have the roomId in the Echo.join because the data is in my event. I'm passsing the value in the call of the event.

Comment: In that case the room id get's passed to the callback so won't be available at the point you begin to listen. If you are using the broadcast event to identify a room that has been joined then you probably want a public channel called 'room'.